# проверка на уникальное поле

Tags: php, html, валидация

Как можно реализовать проверку на уникальность вводимого поля:

схема базы данных:

```html
CREATE TABLE `humans` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `lastname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);
```

файл подключения к бд **config/db.php:**

```html
<?php

$databaseHost = 'localhost';
$databaseName = 'simple';
$databaseUsername = 'root';
$databasePassword = '';

$mysqli = mysqli_connect($databaseHost, $databaseUsername, $databasePassword, $databaseName);

?>
```

html форма:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Добавление</title>
</head>

<body>

 <form action="add.php" method="post" name="form1">
  <table width="25%" border="0">
   <tr>
    <td>Фамилия</td>
    <td>
     <input type="text" name="lastName">
    </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>Имя</td>
    <td>
     <input type="text" name="name">
    </td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td>Отчество</td>
    <td>
     <input type="text" name="patronymic">
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

И сам скрипт , по которому вопрос:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Добавление ++</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php

include_once("./config/db.php");

if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
 $lastName = stripslashes(trim($_POST['lastName']));
 $name = stripslashes(trim($_POST['name']));

 // проверка на пустые поля
 if(empty($lastName) || empty($name) ) {

  if(empty($lastName)) {
   echo "<font color='red'>Заполните фамилию</font><br/>";
  }

  if(empty($name)) {
   echo "<font color='red'>Заполните имя</font><br/>";
  }

  
  //link to the previous page
  echo "<br/><a href='javascript:self.history.back();'>Назад</a>";
 } else {
  // if all the fields are filled (not empty)

  //insert data to database
  $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO humans(lastname,name) VALUES('$lastName','$name')");

  //display success message
  echo "<font color='green'>Успех";
  echo "<br/><a href='index.php'>Результат</a>";
 }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Как мне грамотно провести проверку на то что :

если в базе уже есть такое имя его не добавлять, оставить как есть, а фамилию просто перезаписать не проверять есть она или нет.

Comment: Ради интересу забейте в поле имени или фамилии апостроф, например как в "д'артаньян" и посмотрите что произойдет. На лицо SQL-инъекция. _Никогда_ не подставляйте значения переменных непосредственно в запрос. Используйте привязываемые переменные (см. bind_param)

Comment: @Mike это всё понятно. мне бы хотелось увидеть пример того как мой код можно улучшить

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

{

```
$err = array();
```

$query = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users WHERE login='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login'])."'");

```
if(mysql_result($query, 0) > 0)

{

    $err[] = "Пользователь с таким логином уже существует в базе данных";

}
```

if(count($err) == 0)

```
{
```

$login = $_POST['login'];
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (`login``) VALUES ('$login')");
if ($sql) {
            echo "даные переданы";
        }
        else 
        {
            echo "даные не переданы";
        }

```
    //header("Location: login.php"); exit();

}

else

{

    print "<b>При регистрации произошли следующие ошибки:</b><br>";

    foreach($err AS $error)

    {

        print $error."<br>";

    }

}
```

}

Comment: свои ток данные внеси . и ошибки проще в массиве писать как я показал, чем в echo писать

Comment: не мог бы ты отформатировать, не могу понять ничего - это твоя реализация?

Comment: Да, можно и так сказать,

Comment: http://pastebin.ru/EPaILCun

Comment: ты вроде так просил?

Comment: да то что нужно

Comment: @stas0k Только так делать крайне не рекомендуется. В момент между проверкой на наличие логина из php скрипта и добавлением записи в БД другой пользователь может внести изменения. И на момент insert в БД уже будет существовать дубль. Поэтому для поддержания целостности данных подобные действия _необходимо_ выполнять _одним_ SQL запросом.

Answer (score 3):

Уникальность полей стоит сделать на уровне базы данных. Это не позволит даже ошибкам в приложении внести в базу неверные данные. Вашу таблицу можно объявлять так:

```
CREATE TABLE `humans` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `lastname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY (`name`)
);
```

Уникальный ключ гарантирует, что в БД не смогут оказаться два одинаковых имени.

После этого немного изменяете свой SQL-запрос добавляющий данные:

```
insert into humans(lastname, name)
 values('last','first')
 on duplicate key update lastname=values(lastname);
```

Он выполнит именно то, что вы хотели получить: если имени в БД еще нет - то создаст новую запись, а если есть - изменит фамилию в уже существующей записи.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. а на уровне приложения как мне отловить событие записалось в базу, или уже есть и поле перезаписано. Я думаю что запрос возвращает либо либо другое, правильно ? покажите как обернуть в обработчик ошибки?

Comment: @stas0k http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-affected-rows.php  Обратите внимание на специальный комент в этой статье по поводу "on duplicate"