# INSERT INTO и IF EXIST

Tags: mysql, sql

Смотрите, немного разобрался и пытаюсь выполнить код который проверяет есть ли запись в Таблице, если нету добавляет новую, а если есть изменяет `amount` на 1.

Таблица откуда проверяеться нахождение:

[image: ![Цитата]

Вот код который у меня работает но изминения никакие не происходят, что мне сделать с этим кодом?

```
delimiter $$
create procedure select_or_insert()
begin
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM orders 
            WHERE user_id = '5312312'
            AND name = 'Бургер з куркою') THEN
    update orders set amount = amount + 1 WHERE user_id = '5312312' AND name = 'Бургер з куркою';
    ELSE 
        INSERT INTO orders (user_id, name) VALUES ('1337', '228');
    END IF;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

Вот что мне пишет консоль:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Делаете на связку полей (user_id, name) уникальный ключ, сели его нет, далее insert ... on duplicate key update https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/556627/194569

Comment: *Вот что мне пишет консоль:* А что не нравится в том, что пишет консоль? Она добросовестно сообщает, что процедура создана (а строчкой выше - что удалена). Вот только фигня в том, что создание кода процедуры не означает запуска этого кода на исполнение, для этого существует CALL.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное Akila, не знал этого, так как ещё новичок в SQL